# How to connect Elektron Analog Four's DIN-SYNC output to an 1/8" TRRS jack

Tags: midi

I use an Elektron Analog Four synthesizer (A4) to sequence a Eurorack modular synthesizer.

The A4 has four assignable CV/Gate outputs, as well as two MIDI outputs. One of the MIDI outputs can be configured to send DIN-SYNC instead of MIDI.

Because DIN-SYNC is just an analog clock and reset trigger, I'm thinking I should be able to adapt that output to sync directly with an Intellijel Steppy module without sacrificing any of the four assignable CVs.

BUT

It's unclear to me which cables I should buy to facilitate this. There are various DIN-to-TRS adapters on the market that cater to different implementations of the 1/8" MIDI jack, but I haven't seen anything specifically intended for this purpose.

Does anyone know of a product that can help me here?

Or, failing that, any advice on how to DIY a solution?

I'm trying to avoid buying a whole module just to get an analog clock from midi when the A4 theoretically already has that feature.

Comment: Why are you mentioning TRRS? Does the CLK input really have more than two signals?

Comment: Oh, good point. I got that wrong. I thought the 1/8" midi used TRRS, but you're right, it's just TRS.

Comment: I've edited the original post, it no longer refers to TRRS

Comment: TRS or TS? The Steppy manual does not appear to tell, but I don't think it needs more than two signals on the CLK input. (The DIN SYNC signals are known; the only question is what the Steppy needs.)

Comment: It's true, the click (CLK) input on the Steppy is TS. There's also a reset (RST) input. Where my post mentions "TRS", it's in reference to existing MIDI-to-1/8" adapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the Steppy has a TS jack with the signal at the tip, you need a cable that connects

- pin 2 ↔ sleeve,
- pin 3 ↔ tip.

[image: DIN sync pinout]
<sup>[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DIN-Sync-Steckerbelegung.svg)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. Based on this I should be able to hook up the reset signal as well.

Answer (score 0):

These cables from ALM and Thonk look like they might do the trick:
https://www.thonk.co.uk/shop/alm-dinsnyc-adapator/